# how to change default font in tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts, tailwind-css

I have created a new react project and in my index.css I have added my custom font. I have also added my custom font files.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind variants;
@import url(assets/font/iransans/index.css);

html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family:
    "iransans",
    -apple-system,
    BlinkMacSystemFont,
    "Segoe UI",
    "Roboto",
    "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu",
    "Cantarell",
    "Fira Sans",
    "Droid Sans",
    "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: "iransans", source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas,
    "Courier New", monospace;
}

html {
  scrollbar-gutter: scroll;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family:
    "iransans",
    -apple-system,
    BlinkMacSystemFont,
    "Segoe UI",
    "Roboto",
    "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu",
    "Cantarell",
    "Fira Sans",
    "Droid Sans",
    "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

In tailwin.config.ts I add my font in font family.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["iransans", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        serif: ["iransans", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.serif],
        mono: ["iransans", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.mono],
        iransans: "iransans",
      },
    },
  },

...
}
```

The problem is the font is not applied to all elements by default. For example, if I want to have a span with this custom font, I have to set the font manually.

```
<span className="font-iransans">تست</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override tailwind default fonts, by default, tailwind uses the sans style for everything, which is equivalent to font-sans class, you need to update tailwind.config file like this

```
theme: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["iransans", "Sans-serif"],
        ...,
      },
  },
```

After that by default every element font will change.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#customizing-your-theme

Comment: I already have this in my index.css which I have imported from this. @import url(assets/font/iransans/index.css);
'at' font face {
  font-family: "iransans";
  src: url("./IRANSans(FaNum)_Bold.ttf");
  src: url("./IRANSans(FaNum)_Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
'at' font-face {
  font-family: "iransans";
  src: url("./IRANSans(FaNum)_Medium.ttf");
  src: url("./IRANSans(FaNum)_Medium.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}

Comment: oh sorry after double checking, now I understand what you are asking. If you want to override tailwind default fonts, by default, tailwind uses the sans style for everything, which is equivalent to font-sans class, you need to update tailwind.config theme not in extend object. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your concern.
I have already tried it. It doesn't automatically change the font.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default font used by tailwindcss, you can add the following to your root CSS file, app.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind variants;
....
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font-geist';
  src: url('/fonts/Geist-UltraLight.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@layer base {
  html {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "font-geist", system-ui, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
}
```